# Password resetter [users] is not defined

Tags: laravel

Im stuck with this problem and cant find the solution. looking for some orientation.
Im developing a new proyect with laravel, currently working on user athentication. Im using laravels 5.8 authentication module.

Did some minor changes to the password recovery views, moved reset.blade.php and email.blade.php out of the passwords directory, into the auth parent directory.

[here is the current directory screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIKHI.png)

After that changed the routes to match the previous changes directly on Router.php;

```
>  $this->get('reset','Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
>  $this->post('email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
>  $this->get('reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
>  $this->post('reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');
```

The routing is working correctly, but still keep getting this error "InvalidArgumentException - Password resetter [users] is not defined." on

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager.php

```
>  protected function resolve($name)
>     {
>         $config = $this->getConfig($name);
>         
>         if (is_null($config)) {
>             throw new InvalidArgumentException("Password resetter [{$name}] is not defined.");
>         }
>  
>         // The password broker uses a token repository to validate tokens and send user
>         // password e-mails, as well as validating that password reset process as an
>         // aggregate service of sorts providing a convenient interface for resets.
>         return new PasswordBroker(
>             $this->createTokenRepository($config),
>             $this->app['auth']->createUserProvider($config['provider'] ?? null)
>         );
>     }
```

Thanks!

Still have the problem, no luck with the fix.

Comment: Any suggestions? no luck with this situation

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on your `config/auth.php` configuration file. The laravel reset password default config is:

```
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

If you want to customize the brokers check the documentation again

[Laravel - Password Broker Customization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passwords#password-customization)

Comment: I have exactly that on config/auth.php, sorry i didnt' post that file. The problem persists.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i currently found that the resolve function on PasswordBrokerManager for some strangereason is not reading the config/auth.php file. I have hardcoded the configuration for the password resseter, like this-> $config =["provider" => "users",
        "table" => "password_resets",
        "expire" => 60]; and just like this it works----- please help